# How core file ended up on my system when its limit was set to 0?

Tags: ulimit, core-dump

A file named `core` appeared on my desktop after a reboot. I checked it using `file core` and it seemed that it was created by VLC. The strange thing is when I checked the limit on core files' size using `ulimit -c` it returned 0. So how did this file created?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this file was huge. Its size was around 512MiB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ulimit` is a shell builtin (Verify with `type ulimit`) and only affects the shell and its descendents, you want to check/edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` for system wide settings.